# Summation for nested loops

Tags: math, big-o

I hope my question makes sense. I need to come up with the mathematical summation for the following piece of pseudo-code where S1 and S2 are constant operations

```
          for i ←  1 to n Do
                for j ← i to n Do
                  S1
                      for k ← 1 to j do
                      S2
```

I have attempted to come up with the equation which is

```
T(n) = ∑ni=1 ∑nj=i ∑jk=1 1
```

I tried to solve the inner most loop, that is ∑jk=1 1 and my answer is

```
T(n) = ∑jk=1 1  
T(n) = [k – 1 + 1] * 1
T(n) = k
```

which I am not is correct.

I am not sure how to go about completing this summation as I am confused to what the next steps are in calculating it. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Apologies on the equation syntax I formed above, it did not import properly from Word.

Thank you.

Comment: is n bigger than j?

Comment: Yes I think that is the case

Comment: But how do we arrive at that conclusion? As in what are the follow on steps to reach that conclusion from what I have attempted above.

Answer (score 0):

Your actual runtime is:

> O(f(n,j)) = O(First loop) * O(second loop) * O(third loop)

Therefore the runtime O(f(n,j)) is:

> O(f(n,j)) = n * n * j

We know n > j. So j is negligible with big n.

> O(f(n,j)) = O(f(n)) = O(n^2)

So your problem is element of O(n^2)

Have a look at: 
[Big-O in Docu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)